# IntelliJ IDEA android scala application

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to make an android app in IntelliJ IDEA using scala. I made an android module and a scala module. I'm just after a little hello world for starters.
I added the scala module as a dependency for the android module but when I builde the project("make project") or try to run the thing I get this error:

trouble writing output: format == null

Does anyone know what the problem is?

P.S. In netbeans I can't even add anything as a resource for an android project.

Could it be that this is not the way to do it, do I need to modify the main module's ant script or something? Any pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

I've programmed some android with scala using intellij. However I chose not to use intellij for compilation. Instead I used sbt (http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) with sbt android plugin (https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin) for building and sbt idea processor (https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) to create project files for idea.

Comment: does the android plugin work on windows? all of these don't have much documentation. Read the readme files but they are pretty sketchy. So ... does this work on windows too? If so can you please tell me in more detail what I have to do to end un with an idea project? thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't tested it out with windows so I honestly don't know.

Comment: Start with installing sbt. Then follow the instructions on the android-plugin to create a project from scratch. When you get that to build you can go on to the sbt-idea page and follow the instructions to install and run the processor. After that you should have an intellij project file to open.

Comment: I installed sbt but I can't install the android plugin I read all the documentation but I don't understand how to run it on windows. I dont' have homebrew. I can't run the create_project script. I don't know how to run it. Create_project isn't an exe or a bat it has no extension so when I try to run it windows thinks I am writing a command.

Comment: By the way I read on other blogs that using sbt in this way prohibits me from debugging the scala code even if it worked. Is this so?

Comment: The homebrew part is about installing Android SDK, so if you've installed it in the normal way it should be fine. 

The create_project-script can be run if you install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/). The description says that the script is an alternative way to create the project (to writing the code quoted above on the page). However it does seem that the script includes more, for example creation of the manifest.